# Let $\mathrm{f}: \mathrm{R} \rightarrow \mathrm{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $\mathrm{f}(0)=0........$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, applications

> Question: Let $\mathrm{f}: \mathrm{R} \rightarrow \mathrm{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $\mathrm{f}(0)=0, \mathrm{f}(1)=1$ and $\left|\mathrm{f}^{\prime}(\mathrm{x})\right|<2 \forall \mathrm{x} \in \mathrm{R},$ if a and $\mathrm{b}$ are
> real numbers such that the set of possible values of $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) d x$ is the open interval $(a, b),$ then $(b-a)$ is

My approach:

I figured out that since $f'(x)$ will be bound between -2 and -2 for both $x=0$ and $x=1$, so $f(x)$ should be bounded between $x=0$ and $x=1$ in a quadrilateral like this:[image]
But after this, in order to find the range of $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\cdot dx$,
what shall be done?

I am not able to proceed after this step, please help.

Comment: Your statement of the question breaks off in mid-sentence. Also are the bounds of the integral really $0$ and $1$?

Comment: @RobArthan yes the bounds of the integral are also between 0 and 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using integration by parts. Notice that $$\begin{align*}\int_0^1 f(x)dx &= xf(x)\Big|_0^1 - \int_0^1xf'(x)dx \\ &= 1 - \int_0^1 xf'(x)dx\end{align*}$$
Since $-2 < f'(x) < 2$ for all $x$, then $-\int_0^1 2x dx < \int_0^1 xf'(x)dx < \int_0^1 2xdx$. So $-1 < \int_0^1 xf'(x)dx < 1$, futher $-1 < -\int_0^1 xf'(x)dx < 1$. This fact combined with the integration by parts above yields that
$$\begin{align*}1 - 1 < 1 - \int_0^1 xf'(x)dx &< 1- (-1)\\
0 < 1 - \int_0^1 xf'(x)dx &< 2 \\ 
0 < \int_0^1 f(x)dx &< 2\end{align*}$$
My estimate would tell you that $\int_0^2f(x)dx\in (0,2)$ and so $(b-a) = 2-0 = 2$.